# Can't install Orange

Tags: enthought, orange

I am having real problems installing any kind of version of Orange either on Windows 7, Windows 8 or Ubuntu.

I used to have a version of Orange working on a different computer and I believe it might have stopped working when I installed enthought canopy. Both my windows 7 and 8 machines also have had enthought installed. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both systems but I can not get it to work.

In windows the icon appears on the desktop but it does nothing when I click on it, the target of the icon is 'C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\pythonw.exe -m Orange.OrangeCanvas.main'

In linux (ubuntu) I have installed the normal version of Orange, but half the widgets do not appear, even smiple ones like view a data table etc. It also looks like an older version then what I used to have on Windows.

I also installed Orange3 on ubuntu but again this did not have all the widgets I used to have on my old windows version of Orange and it generally did not seem finished.

Does anyone know of any problems with having enthought and orange installed? What can I do to resolve this? (I have uninstalled enthought but Orange still does not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Orange canvas from the command prompt

```
C:\Users\localadmin\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\python.exe -m Orange.OrangeCanvas.main -l3
```

or with a standard python install

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -m Orange.OrangeCanvas.main -l3
```

This should give you more information about the error.

Comment: I get 'dll load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application' is this something to do with 64bit or 32bit python versions? Which version is Orange meant to have?

Comment: Ok so I reinstalled python2.7 32 bit and Orange now loads.. there are some errors when launching from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a Windows machine. I installed Orange and it reported the installation to be correct. However, when I clicked on the desktop icon, nothing happened. If I tried to run Orange from the command prompt, I got no errors, warnings or anything, but the program still didn't start.

Eventually I uninstalled Python and all Python libraries. I had several previously installed Python libraries/packages before I installed Orange. Removing all and performing a reinstallation of Orange and the required libraries fixed the issue.